# Why is the unit normal of plane curves defined to be rotated?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ be a regular smooth curve given as $\gamma (t) = (x(t), y(t))$ moving at unit speed.

Then the unit normal $N$ is defined to be

$$ N(t) = (-y'(t), x'(t))$$

that is, the "usual" unit normal,

$$ N(t) = \gamma^{''}(t)/\|\gamma(t)^{''}\|$$

rotated by ${\pi \over 2}$.

I don't understand why the case $n=2$ needs this different definition.

> Please could someone explain to me why we have to rotate the normal
>   vector if $n=2$?

Comment: In what way is $\dot{\gamma}(t)/\|\dot{\gamma(t)}\|$ a normal vector? It seems to me it is tangent to the curve.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry I made a typo in the definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In [this book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Curves_and_Singularities.html?id=rhq3YCguBOUC) on page 29 the "usual" unit normal (i.e. if $n \ge 3$) is defined as $N(t) = \gamma^{''}(t)/\|\gamma(t)^{''}\|$.

Comment: Now that you've corrected the typo, the confusion is resolved: $\bigl(-y'(t),x'(t)\bigr)$ is clearly not the same as $\bigl(x''(t),y''(t)\bigr)$ rotated by $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of the normal to a curve is given by the component of the *second* derivative of the position which is orthogonal to the tangent.

The planar case is simpler in that the curve torsion is always null, so that the normal is just the perpendicular to the tangent and can be computed from the *first* derivative instead.

---

In the 3D formula for the normal,

$$N=\frac{\dot r\times(\ddot r\times\dot r)}{||\dot r||\ ||\ddot r\times\dot r||},$$
the product $\ddot r\times\dot r$ is parallel to the $z$ axis and perpendicular to $\dot r$, so that a nice simplification is possible
$$N=\frac{\dot r\times u_z}{||\dot r||}.$$
This is indeed the rotated tangent vector.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have read the first sentence of your answer many many times but I just don't understand it. Please could you rephrase it? Maybe it's just a language problem (I suppose your native language is not English). A component is just one entry in a vector so it cannot be orthogonal to anything. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am referring to the decomposition in a parallel and an orthogonal component. This is a matter of terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x'^2+y'^2=1$, we have that $x'x''+y'y''=0$. Thus, $(x'',y'')\perp(x'y')$. Since $n=2$, we can rotate by $\frac\pi2$ to get
$$
(-y',x')\parallel(x'',y'')
$$
and
$$
\|(-y',x')\|=1
$$
Therefore,
$$
(-y',x')=\pm\frac{(x'',y'')}{\|(x'',y'')\|}
$$
In $\mathbb{R}^2$ there is only one direction perpendicular to the tangent. In higher dimensions, the situation is not so simple.

Comment: But why does it differ from $n\ge3$ ?

Comment: Because there is only one direction perpendicular to the tangent in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Right, that's what the question is about.

Comment: and so I've added that to my answer. I'd sort of hinted at it with the "Since $n=2$" sentence.